# Is there a relation on Hodge numbers, weaker than $h^{2,0}=0$, that implies a compact Kähler manifold is projective?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory

The Kodaira embedding theorem yields as a corollary that a compact Kähler manifold $X$ with $h^{2,0} =0$ is projective.

Is there a weaker relation on Hodge numbers that implies that a compact Kähler manifold is projective?

Comment: You can't say much from the Hodge numbers $h^{pq}$ alone. Eg there are non-projective K3 surfaces (with $h^{2,0}=1$) and non-projective abelian surfaces (with $h^{2,0}=2$).